# Parsing Date/Time Formats in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large database that I copy and paste from a website into an Excel 2007 document.  One particular column always gives me trouble.  The column is formatted as dd mmm hhmm for the day, month, and 24 hour time:

```
18 NOV 2300
```

The problem is that Excel interprets this as dd mmm yyyy if the four-digit number is 1900 or greater, so the above is taken to be the 18th of November in the year 2300, rather than 11:00 PM on November 11 of the current year. It then formats this value as dd-mmm-yy (day, month, and two digit year) for display.  I can go in and change those but it always reads the time as a year when it is 1900 or greater and autoformats appropriately.  You can change the format of the block to text and try to copy and paste but Excel will still automatically format the date and time when you copy and paste the database into Excel.  You can test this out by simply copying and pasting anything in that format with a time greater than 1900.  10 FEB 2030 for example.  I need Excel to stop automatically formatting in this fashion.

I don't actually need `18 NOV 2300` to be translated as 11:00 PM on November 11 of the current year; I just need it to be *displayed* as `18 NOV 2300`.

Comment: First of all, 24-hour time is commonly expressed as “hhmm”, not “tttt”. Secondly, I suspect that you mean to say, “it interprets the time as a year when it is ***1900*** or greater”. Thirdly, what happens when you type (or paste) `18 NOV 1500`? Do you get “11 / 18 / _(current year)_ 3:00:00 PM”, or do you get a string? If you get Excel to interpret `18 NOV 1500` (dd mmm hhmm) as a date/time, how are you doing that? If it leaves it as a string, isn’t that a problem for you, too? Why aren’t you asking for help about that? Do you have a solution that handles that case?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I did mean "hhmm" and also 1900.  I will correct that.  You can type or paste 20 DEC 1950 and you will get 20-Dec-50.  If you convert that to text using the format cells option you get a string of 720.  If the date is displayed as text only, it is not a problem.  I just need it displayed properly.  I don't need to do calculations of any sort with these dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you willing to use a “helper column”?  If you’re pasting the “dd mmm hhmm” data into Column `P` (let’s assume starting at `P2` and going down), put

```
=TEXT(P2,"dd mmm yyyy")
```

into cell `Q2` and drag/fill down. 
This basically reverses the interpretation that Excel did on the input string,
reconstituting what got parsed as the day, month, and year. 
Strings that didn’t get interpreted as dates
(because the four-digit number is less than 1900) are simply passed through unchanged.

This will cause blank cells in Column `P` to be translated into `00 Jan 1900`. 
If you don’t like that, use

```
=IF(P2<>"", TEXT(P2,"dd mmm yyyy"), "")
```

instead.

This will represent months with the typical initial capital (Mmm, e.g., “Nov”). 
If you want it all caps, use

```
=IF(P2<>"", UPPER(TEXT(P2,"dd mmm yyyy")), "")
```

Comment: That last formula is something I can definitely work with.  I'll play around a little more and see what I can come up with.  I think this is the best solution I've seen thus far.  Thank you Scott.

Comment: Just following up.  It has been a few days now and it seems that the last formula you provided works perfectly.  Thank you again Scott!

Comment: I’m glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't Copy/Paste directly into Excel.  Doing so allows Excel to format the result as it sees fit.  Instead Paste into something like **NotePad** and save the result as a text file.  You can the use Excel's Import Wizard to read the text file.  You can tell the Wizard exactly how the field should be interpreted.

Comment: This is a good idea, but would actually take longer than manually changing 5-10 dates that fall into that category.  Excel non-powerusers need to do this as well.  They can barely figure out how to format cells to text and change the dates, let alone import something.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override Excel trying to be "smart" with the dates by pasting just the values, and no formatting information. Or if that doesn't work, then paste using the source formatting.

Comment: You can type the information in manually if you want.  It will still change the formatting automatically no matter what in the instance I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't (well, didn't seven years ago) need the entry to be a real time available for calculations, the simplest way of all to make such an entry is to simply start by typing an apostrophe, then the literal entry you wish to make. So...

```
'18 NOV 2300
```

No need for formulas and worrying about how Excel has done this with dates and other numerical entries for 35 years. Just begin with the apostrophe then type what you would have typed anyway.