# Parse dates like "20220928" in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, date

I have an input column which contains an id + datetime:

```
id12345!20220926_100911
```

My goal is to get the date and I have already successfully extracted the date *into text* with a formula involving `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `FIND`. The result is now:

```
20220926
20220927
20220928
```

**How to make Excel interpret this column *as dates* in yyyymmdd format?** (So that I can, for example, filter by year, month, etc.)

Note: I have already read [Parsing Date/Time Formats in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/677486/parsing-date-time-formats-in-excel) but it didn't help here.

Comment: Show us the formular used in the cells of this column. [Edit] your question please.

Comment: @help-info.de I edited to add context. The `"id12345!20220926_100911" => "20220926"` extraction already works (and is out-of-topic of the question). The goal is now to parse this `"20220926"` text into a date format. (For example, so that we can filter by month, year in Filter)

Comment: Is the exclamation mark always before the date? Is the date always followed by an underscore? Is yes and assuming the text is for example in cell B2, you can use the formula: `=MID(B2, SEARCH("!", B2)+1, SEARCH("_", B2) - SEARCH("!", B2) -1)`

Comment: If the goal for interpreting as date is simply for filter logic, then could you create another column and just extract the first 6 from this column? That would represent YYYYMM. You could even add a hyphen in between the YYYY and MM if you wanted.

Comment: @Isolated The great thing in Excel when a column is interpreted as dates, is that you have various filtering possibilities: 03 is automatically written as March in the filter, then you can combine a few months from different years, and some specific days as well etc. That is why I really want to have a full parsing as date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the date is in an unambiguous format, you can create a text string date and then turn it into a value:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"0000\/00\/00")
```

Format the result as a date

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! I'm curious *why* it works: TEXT says "convert a number to text", here it's the contrary. Also in your pattern you have `\/`, and in your screenshot we see `-` as separator, is it a special feature? PS: is `=--` a known trick in Excel? Thanks again!

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, the TEXT function is used to *create a text string date*.  The double unary `--` *turns it into a value*.  (You could also use `VALUE` or `DATEVALUE` to the same effect).  The formatting of the date in B1 is dependent on the cell formatting, and has absolutely nothing to do with the text string format that we originally created. When you tried it, and your cell was originally formatted as `General`. what did you see? To better understand the process, with the formatting set to `General`, use the `Formula Evaluation` tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RonRosenfeld! Please copy/paste these informations into the answer, it will be very useful for future reference :)

Answer (score 1):

Excel has a function for this precise purpose:  `DATE`.

You currently generate the components as described and that is working, so keep doing so. However, instead of concatenating them in whatever manner into the strings you show (such as "20220926") use the components in the `DATE`function:

```
=DATE( generated year string, generated month string, generated day string )
```

Its output is a date for Excel purposes and Excel is happy to let you format the cell with any date format you wish. `yyyymmdd` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Given the 20220925  format slice this up into Year Month Day columns with Left() and Mid()  and convert with the value() function then put that in date().

| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 | F1 | G1 | H1 | I1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| --------- | --------- | ------------- |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20220923 | =LEFT(A1,4) | =MID(A1,5,2) | =MID(A1,7,2) | =VALUE(B1) | =VALUE(C1) | =VALUE(D1) | =DATE(E1,F1,G1) |  |
| 20220317 | =LEFT(A2,4) | =MID(A2,5,2) | =MID(A2,7,2) | =VALUE(B2) | =VALUE(C2) | =VALUE(D2) | =DATE(E2,F2,G2) |  |

[Conversion formula ] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YczIn.jpg)

[Conversion results] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnbNp.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a nice way to have this done in 1 column only? (I would like to avoid to have many columns for this parsing in my data spreadsheet).

Comment: @Basj   I spread them out for clarity       H1 first cell could be =date(value(left(a1,4)),value(mid(a1,5,2),value(mid(a1m7,2)))  which is all the calculation folded into on but is harder to understand.